# cx freeze does not work

Tags: python, wxpython, cx-freeze

i am new to python, i have wrote script using python and wxpython in linux machine. Now i want convert .py to .exe ,i used cxfreeze for that purpose. steps followed to create exe

```
        $ python setup.py build
        $ python setup.py install
        $ python pip cxfreeze
        $ cxfreeze script.py
```

But when i execute "./script(the exe)" in other system i get this error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
 File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
 File "ExtensionLoader_wx__core_.py", line 18, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named None
```

Comment: I wish I spent enough time with cxfreeze to help.  I'm personally a fan of py2exe, and recently added 64-bit bundle-files support to it.  I know it works with wx as well.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: is py@exe works for linux? or any other .py to .exe creater in linux

Comment: You could check out pyinstaller.  I didn't like it's two-pass mode, but it may fit your need.

Comment: Last time I have tried on Linux, I have been running cx_freeze like this: `cxfreeze my_script.py --target-dir=../Bin/Bin --target-name=Executable_name --include-modules=encodings.ascii,encodings.utf_8,encodings.idna`.

Comment: If you're copying it to another system, you need to copy all the files from the build or dist folder. If there are some `.so` files, it won't work without them.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to use cxfreeze on CentOS using the following simple wxPython app:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test EXE", size=(1024, 768))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        lbl = wx.StaticText(panel, label="This is a binary program!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The output when copied to a Windows 7 box won't work at all. It is creating files for CentOS, NOT Windows! No surprise there since I'm running the script on a Linux box. If you run cxfreeze on Windows, you'll end up with some DLL files in your output. Either way, when you run the exe it generates on Windows, it works. When you run the file it creates on CentOS, it works. But if you try to copy the files that were generated for that OS to a different OS, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure that answers the question, but you're quite right: cx_Freeze can create Windows, Linux & Mac executables, but you can't freeze on one platform for another one.

Comment: Well he wanted to know if he could create a Windows executable with cx_freeze on Linux and I created a small demo that shows that you cannot.

Comment: I don't think he's actually asking about Windows executables, despite the mention of .exe . You wouldn't run it as `./script` on Windows, and I don't think it would get far enough to give you a Python error message.

Comment: Actually, I got a very similar error message to his when I tried to run the generated code from a Linux box on a Windows box. But you could be right.

Comment: That's interesting. Did you have Cygwin or something like that installed on the Windows machine? Linux and Windows have different executable formats, so I wouldn't have thought it was able to run it.